# Reach OpenVPN Server from local network once connected

Tags: routing, openvpn, ifconfig

I've installed an OpenVPN Server in my VPS with CentOS, it's working fine. I can connect from Windows and navigate with internet connection, but I want to be able to reach my VPS from the local network.

I can only ping the gateway, from the pc and the VPS. I'm not able to ping the VPS from the PC and viceversa, how can I fix it?

I think I must be missing some routing rule.

## ifconfig:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet *.*.*.*  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast *.*.*.*
        inet6 ****::****:****:****:****  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether **:**:**:**:**:**  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 7201519  bytes 1165018500 (1.0 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5807292  bytes 1621774031 (1.5 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::2  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x80<compat,global>
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 823269  bytes 682966386 (651.3 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 823269  bytes 682966386 (651.3 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.8.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 10.8.0.2
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100
```

- Gateway is 10.8.0.1
- My VPS local ip is 10.8.0.2
- My PC gets 10.8.0.6

Comment: What is the router on your local network? Have you connected to the VPN from there? (Normally, if you want to provide access to everything on the LAN, that'd be your VPN endpoint)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure if I know what you mean, I've connected from OpenVPN client for Windows. Do you mean my phisical router?

Comment: Yeah, all the PCs on your LAN send any traffic not destined for other machines on the LAN (as determined by the IP address and subnet mask) to the router. So normally if you want to route something over a VPN, you'd run the VPN endpoint on the router.

Comment: You could have your router then send that traffic back to a PC on your LAN (at least if it has that option); then configure your Windows machine to forward it (off-topic here, of course). Of course, you'll also need to configure the VPS to reach your LAN via the VPN (add a routing table entry for that—you can do this in the OpenVPN config with the `route` option). That last part is definitely on-topic here.